# in apex pie chart how can i display label outside it

Tags: reactjs, pie-chart, apex

```
const chartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    series: [...crops.map(crop => crop.no_of_plants), remainingCapacity],
    labels: [...crops.map(crop => crop.crop_name), 'Empty'],
    colors: ['#FFEFD5', '#B2DFDB', '#FFCDD2', '#E1BEE7', '#FFF9C4', '#DCEDC8','#f5f5f5'],
    legend: {
      position: 'bottom',
      fontSize: '8px',
      height: 15, // Set a fixed height for the legend container
      offsetY: 10,
      onItemHover: {
        highlightDataSeries: true
      }
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
position: 'outside',
offsetX: 30,
offsetY: 30,
      style: {
        fontSize: '10px'
      },
      

    }
  };
```

i tried puttin a offsetX to 30 but its not working